# DIV same height as parent

Tags: html, css

So, I have two DIVs, being that the second one has variable content. I need the first DIV to have the same height as the second one, and the text on it to be vertically centered.
I've found several pages with similar examples, but I haven't found a good way of doing it.
Thanks in advance!

~like this: http://jsfiddle.net/a8LjU/4/

Comment: You haven't found a "good" way of doing it because there isn't one. You'll need to nest them in intermediary container divs. http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks

Comment: I see. Well there isn't a better way to deal with this? If not, I'll just have to work with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

page.css:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="first">
  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT
</div>
<div class="second">
  TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT         
</div>
</div>​
```

default.css:

```
body{
  height:100%;
}
html{
  height:100%;
}

.container{
  float:left;
  height:100%;
}

.first, .second{
  float:left;
  background:#00C8FF;
  height:100%;
  width:50px;
}

.second{
  background:#006EFF;
}
```

Bear in mind that this will put the height of both at the height of the containing page. There's not really a pretty way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I actually ended up adding the background color from the static div to the container, and didn't aligned the text vertically...

Comment: @Derik A good solution, just watch out for the second div being shorter as the background color will extend past the "column" height.

Comment: Yeah i thought about that too haha min-height on the variable column! and thx!

Answer (score 1):

Using the css display properties of `table` and `table-cell` can work, but it's not supported across all browsers like IE7 and below.

I've updated your example with the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/a8LjU/5/

An alternative is using intermediary divs and the method can be found here: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks